# How to dynamically change the color of a country on d3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

```js
var COLOR = 'blue';
var map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('map'),
  responsive: false,
});

function changeColor(countryCode) {
  map.updateChoropleth({
    countryCode: COLOR
  });
}

setInterval(function() {
  changeColor('USA');
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datamaps/0.5.8/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

I have the following javascript which renders a world map on HTML.

```
var map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('map'),
  responsive: true,
});

function changeColor(countryCode) {
  map.updateChoropleth({
    countryCode: 'blue'
  });
  console.log(countryCode + '--> colorChange');
}

setInterval(function() {
  changeColor('USA');
}, 2000);
```

I want to update the color of a particular country after a 2s. When I run the above code, the function *changeColor* is called after every 2s, but the function *map.updateChoropleth* does not seem to have any effect. In case, I change the following snippet:

```
function changeColor(countryCode) {
  map.updateChoropleth({
    countryCode: 'blue'
  });
  console.log(countryCode + '--> colorChange');
}
```

to

```
function changeColor(countryCode) {
  map.updateChoropleth({
    "USA": 'blue'
  });
  console.log(countryCode + '--> colorChange');
}
```

the function works as expected. Why does this not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `updateChoropleth` function is looking for a property key literally named `countryCode`.

A solution is populating an object and passing it to the function:

```js
var COLOR = 'blue';
var map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById('map'),
  responsive: false,
});

function changeColor(countryCode) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[countryCode] = COLOR;
  map.updateChoropleth(obj);
}

setInterval(function() {
  changeColor('USA');
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datamaps/0.5.8/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datamaps/0.5.8/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
      <div id="map" class="world-map"></div>
      <script>
        // https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3

        var defaultColor = '#c3c3c3';
        var activeColor = '#00b3c6';
        var highlightColorHover = '#037582';
        var highlightBorderColor = '#037582';

        var map = new Datamap({
          element: document.getElementById('map'),
          responsive: false,
          fills: {
            defaultFill: defaultColor
          },
          geographyConfig: {
            highlightFillColor: highlightColorHover,
            highlightBorderColor: highlightBorderColor,
          },
        });

        map.updateChoropleth({
          USA: activeColor,
          MEX: activeColor,
          PAN: activeColor,
          ARG: activeColor,
          BRA: activeColor,
          CHL: activeColor,
          COL: activeColor,
          AUT: activeColor,
          BEL: activeColor,
          BGR: activeColor,
          DNK: activeColor,
          FIN: activeColor,
          FRA: activeColor,
          DEU: activeColor,
          HUN: activeColor,
          IRL: activeColor,
          ITA: activeColor,
          LTU: activeColor,
          NLD: activeColor,
          POL: activeColor,
          PRT: activeColor,
          ROU: activeColor,
          RUS: activeColor,
          ESP: activeColor,
          SWE: activeColor,
          CHE: activeColor,
          TUR: activeColor,
          GBR: activeColor,
          CHN: activeColor,
          IND: activeColor,
          JPN: activeColor,
          MYS: activeColor,
          PAK: activeColor,
          SGP: activeColor,
          AUS: activeColor,
          ARE: activeColor,
          ZAF: activeColor,
        });
      </script>
```